# run gwt in server mode

Tags: eclipse, gwt

I'm trying to use eclipse 3.6 with Google Web Toolkit and I don't see there an option to run the app on the server. When I click on Run, there is automatically the hosted mode, when I click the `Run as...` there is option `1. Run as application` , `2. Run as applet` - which is useless, `3. Run as Web application` - which leads to running in hosted mode. During creation of GWT project, ide even doesn't ask about target server, like it does when creating the other web apps. Isn't there such an option or I'm just overlooking it?

Comment: whats wrong with the hosted mode? the two other alternatives are (1) compile + manual deploy on your favorite servlet container (read tomcat/jetty).  (2) one-click deploy to google app engine (requires google account + google app engine project created)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `-noserver` option. See [here](http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/4500) for some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have my eclipse installation handy at the moment, but I believe that ["Google Plugin for Eclipse"](http://code.google.com/eclipse/) gives you the option to run the GWT app in an external server. If you already have GPE installed, try updating to latest version of the plugin.

You might also want to checkout this FAQ entry:

http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/faq.html#gwt_in_eclipse_for_java_ee

Comment: i have the GPE - latest version, but the option is not there and the FAQ page `http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/running_and_debugging_2_0.html` is very abstract about running on server

Comment: Have you checked the link to faq entry? It have a step by step guide http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/faq.html#gwt_in_eclipse_for_java_ee

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run development mode as a server to other computers, include the bindAddress switch in the command line.  E.g. -bindAddress 192.168.0.35 (or whatever address).  You add arguments to the command line by choosing "Run configurations..." from the run menu.

This is still running in development mode.  If you want to deploy to a production server, click the red "Gwt compile" toolbox and then copy your war folder to your server manually.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we are doing an web application with GWT. We are not using eclipse but using GWT4NB Netbeans plugins. It allows us to compile GWT in netbeans and deploy the web application to any server which in our case is Glassfish 2. We are also using EJB and communication with RPC. We call ServiceImpl from RPC and call EJB methods from ServiceImpl.

So, I believe you could do something eclipse also, create a war and then deploy to any servlet container probably Tomcat or Glassfish.